# Web en React se cuelga, DevTools was disconnected from the page

Tags: reactjs, redux

estoy haciendo una pagina donde realizo algunas operaciones pero si quiero realizar muy rapido estas mismas se cuelga la pagina. Tengo 2 tabs con una tabla cada una y al cambiar de tabs carga su respectiva tabla, pero en general cuando cambio de una Tab a otra tarda basante y se termina colgando. Les adjunto una foto por si alguno me puede ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy general, es complicado ir a lo particular sin poder ver el código y aunque compartieras un repo, sería una labor grande, sugiero que vayas revisando componente por componente con [Performance Tools](https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html) e intentar encontrar cuales componentes dan mas complejidad para posteriormente, hacer el [refactor correspondiente](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html).